# Use variable as dict key in django templates

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I have two dict with the same keys. I use one dict to build table but I don't know how to get access to other dict.

Example

```
{% for key1, item1 for dict1.items %}
    {% for key2, item2 for item1.items %}
        <p>{{ item2.value }}</p>
        <p>there should be value from dict2</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

In python I can use dict2[key1][key2]["value"] but how do this with template?

Comment: Can you please share your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either have to write one more for loop which isn't a good idea performance-wise.

But you can write a custom template filter:

```
@register.filter
def get_value(data, key):
    return data.get(key)
```

And then in your template:

```
{% load custom_tags %}
{{ dict2|get_value:"key" }}
```

You can also do multiple:

```
{{ dict2|get_value:"key"|get_value:"key2" }}
```

take a look at docs for more details:

[Custom template tags and filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/)

Answer (score 0):

What you here basically aim to do is move business logic in the template. Django's template language deliberately did not implement function calls with arguments and subscripting, to give people more incentive to write the business logic in the view. If you really want to use subscripting, you can use the [*jinja* template renderer](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/).

You can preprocess the dictionary by merging hte two dictionaries, like:

```
result = {
    k1 : {
        k2 : (v1, dict2[k1][k2]['value'])
        for k2, v1 in subd.items()
    }
    for k1, subd in dict1.items()
}
```

You can then iterate over the dictionary in the template, like:

```
{% for key1, item for result.items %}
    {% for key2, vs for item1.items %}
        <p>{{ vs.0.value }}</p>
        <p>{{ vs.1 }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

so here `vs.1` contains the corresponding `dict2[key1][key2][value]`.

Comment: Thanks, that is good idea. I will make one more step and complitly merge both from the start.